# Blade components inheritance for displaying collections. Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-7

- Laravel Version: 7.6.2
- PHP Version: 7.3.7
- Database Driver & Version: 10.3.16-MariaDB

  #### Description:

I have couple anonymous components.  Component `abstract` contain two blade `yields`. In the `excerpt` i want to define these sections, but it seems to be not working.
The problem is that every post has the same `post-content` and `post-additions`. Each one has content and link like the first post. Everything which is not overriden in `excerpt` is displayed in the right way. I have used the same methodology in Laravel 6 and there were no problems.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Loop over all posts `views\components\posts\catalogue.blade.php`:

```
@forelse($posts as $post)
    <x-posts.representations.excerpt :post="$post"
                                     :class="($loop->last) ? 'post_box_last' : ''" />
@empty
    <h3>Unfortunately, there are no posts for you..</h3>
@endforelse
```

Post component `views\components\posts\representations\excerpt.blade.php`:

```
@extends('components.posts.representations.abstract')
@props(['post'])

@section('post-content')
    <p>{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
@endsection

@section('post-additions')
    <a href="{{ route('main.posts.show', ['post' => $post->uri_alias]) }}" class="more float_r">Continue Reading</a>
@endsection
```

Abstract post representation `views\components\posts\representations\abstract.blade.php`:

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'post_box']) }}>
    ...
    <div class="post_box_right">
        <h2>{{ $post->name }}</h2>
        ...

        @yield('post-content')

        @yield('post-additions')
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I'm having the same issue :-(

Comment: Yep, I googled high and low and finally found solution. Answer is down here.

Comment: Great, thanks! Funny thing is that I've asked the question on the Laravel github and the main man himself Taylor replied but gave me a completely different answer :-)

Comment: What answer Taylor gave?

Comment: "Use a parent component": https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I solved this out in one simple action:**
In my derived component i replaced `@endsection` with `@overwrite` where i had issue.

Comment: This really helped me out, thanks. I was stuck on this for ages.